# Adding to the $PATH environment variable in a PHP script

Tags: php, path, environment-variables

I have a PHP script that is using `wget` to download some images. However, `wget` was installed using [Homebrew](https://brew.sh/) so it's not available to the user running the PHP script. When I run `exec('echo $PATH')` I don't get the `/usr/local/bin` directory that contains `wget`. How do I add `/usr/local/bin` to the environment path so the PHP script can find `wget`?

**Update:** I forgot to mention the reason I can't specify the exact location is because the location may be different depending on which machine this script is being run on.

### Solution:

This is what I ended up with:

```
//help PHP find wget since it may be in /usr/local/bin
putenv('PATH=' . getenv('PATH') . PATH_SEPARATOR . '/usr/local/bin');
if (exec('which wget') == null) {
    throw new Exception('Could not find wget, so image could not be downloaded.');
}

//now we know wget is available, so download the image
exec('wget ...');
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

In order of preference:

1. You can simply specify the full path `/usr/local/bin/wget` when you are calling the subprocess. This is probably the simplest and best approach.
2. You can use [`proc_open`](http://ca.php.net/manual/en/function.proc-open.php) instead of `exec`, which allows you to pass environment variables as an argument.
3. You can use [`putenv`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.putenv.php) to change the current environment (which will be inherited by subprocesses).

Comment: Sorry, is `putenv` valid only for the current request? New request won't have the new added path, correct?

Comment: The [PHP documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/function.putenv.php) indicates it does not survive beyond the current request.

Answer (score 2):

PHP has a magic global variable called `$_ENV` which is an array holding all environment variables (in the context of the process the PHP script runs in, e.g. your web server).

see http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.environment.php