# Append to the Apache Environment Path

Tags: php, macos, apache, environment-variables

I have a web accessible PHP script that is using a shell command to drop PDFs to text.  I installed Poppler, and am using pdftotext, via MacPorts.  I am able to run the command successfully from the CL, and when supplying the full path within the PHP script to '/opt/local/bin/pdftotext'.  So, I know that my $PATH is correct and the permissions are sufficient, yet I am still getting an exit status of 127: Command Not Found, when attempting to do simply 'pdftotext' in the exec().

I have tried the answers from [How do I add paths to the Apache PATH variable?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2837697/how-do-i-add-paths-to-the-apache-path-variable) and http://lists.apple.com/archives/macos-x-server/2008/Sep/msg00433.html.  I modified both the /etc/paths and /etc/profile, and added /etc/paths.d/macports all pointing to '/opt/local/bin'.  setenv, apache_setenv, etc all had no effect also.

I am using a MAMP (1.9 I think) install for my local development, OSX 10.6, PHP 5.3.5, all a little behind I know :-) ... my $PATH is modified to point to the MAMP bin/php

Answer (score 1, accepted):

/etc/paths.d/macports will influence on PATH variable for macports, not for the Apache. You probably need to add /etc/parhs.d/apache (or else) to do what you need.
**Edit**: also check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3428647/php-exec-path-variable-missing-elements) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6901583/adding-to-the-path-environment-variable-in-a-php-script) threads for solutions. It is somewhat outdated but still can help.

Comment: so the name of the file in /etc/paths.d is for the process requesting the path, not the name of what the path is for?  sadly, adding both 'apache' and 'php' had no effect.

Comment: @WayneWeibel I've added links to the answer - check may be you'll find solution there.

Comment: Thanks. The links did help. I was able to at least get the path correct using putenv.  Still a little hacky for my taste, may switch to proc_open for executing the command. The shell is 'sh' that PHP is using, so next is making the correct .profile (hopefully). Thanks again.