# PHP exec command works in shell and php command line but not on website

Tags: php, exec

I have a problem where I am trying to copy a file that is generated on a server drive that I have mounted using the php exec command.  However, the command doesn't work (although the return status is 1) when called from a web-page.

```
$src = "/mnt/...";
$dest = "/var/www/...";
exec("cp $src $dest");
```

I have tried printing out the command to make sure it is correct, and it is.  I have also tried making sure the file exists before attempting to copy it and it is.

```
if (file_exists($src)) {
    exec("cp $src $dest");
}
```

Copying the command directly into the terminal works.

```
$ >cp /mnt/... /var/www/...
```

I've also tried using the php command line tool to run the exec command and that also works.

```
$ >php -r 'exec("cp /mnt/... /var/www/...");'
```

I have also tried using `shell_exec` as well, with the same results.

Comment: This is probably because php is being run under a different user on the system, and that that user does not have the rights to do that action on those files. You could look into sudo to perform this

Comment: Wouldn't I get a status code of 0 then?

Comment: Last time I had this error, I didn't think of looking at the status code so I can't be sure of that, sorry. But using sudo did fix my problems

Comment: I bet PHP doesn't have permissions to either copy the file from source, or it doesn't have permissions to copy to the destination. Or it could be both.

Comment: Try to check `is_writable($dest)`.  Chances are it's `false`, which means, as others have said, the PHP user cannot write to it.  Usually PHP is ran as the `apache` (`www-data`) or `nobody` user.  Run `echo exec("whoami");` to see the user it's running as.

Answer (score 1):

Hostings usually disable the shell commands.
On your local, you can edit your `php.ini` and add this line to disable the functions you want:

```
disable_functions =exec,passthru,shell_exec,system,proc_open,popen,curl_exec,curl_multi_exec,parse_ini_file,show_source
```

But on your live website, you need to contact your host provider to enable the functions that are disabled by default.

Answer (score 0):

You can add the second parameter to help debug, `$output` will display what the `cp` command is doing, whether it be an error or not.

I would also recommend placing quotes around the files, just in case something with a space gets in there.

```
$src = "/mnt/...";
$dest = "/var/www/...";
exec("cp '$src' '$dest'", $output, $retrun_var);

var_dump($output, $retrun_var);
```

Answer (score 0):

I had a [similar issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15619071/append-to-the-apache-environment-path) a while ago.  It was essentially what all the commentators are saying.  The user/permission of the web server are restricted, but also the shell environment that is being used and/or the PATH environment variable.